# How to unzip a file with ruby

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

Okay I've found the following code for unzippping a file with Ruby.

```
def unzip_file (file, destination)
    Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) { |zip_file|
        zip_file.each { |f|
            f_path=File.join("destination_path", f.name)
            FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
            zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
        }
    }
end
```

Above this I'm using the following to ensure the needed gems are installed.

```
begin
    require 'rubygems'
rescue LoadError
    'gem install rubygems'
end
begin
    require 'zip/zip'
rescue LoadError
    'gem install rubyzip'
end
```

So when I call unzip_file I get the following error:

```
in `unzip_file': uninitialized constant Zip (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Just try `::Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) ..`

Comment: "gem install rubygems" And then there was light.

Comment: I would be very surprised if a Ruby script started installing gems on its own. Better to simply abort on `LoadError` and yell at the user to install the gem themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with installing the gem that way is that you're shelling out to another process with:

```
`gem install rubyzip`
```

and after that finishes installing the gem, your current `irb` session still won't see it. You'd have to reload `irb` with `exec "irb"` and then calling `require 'zip'` again.

*Note: those are backticks not single quotes.*

Try this:

```
begin
    require 'zip'
rescue LoadError
    `gem install rubyzip`
    exec "irb"
    retry
end
```

For me `require 'zip'` works. I have rubyzip-1.1.2

Now you should be able to use `Zip`

Also, the `gem` command *is* rubygems. So you can't install rubygems with itself. It should already be installed, but if not try this: http://rubygems.org/pages/download

Answer (score 4):

Beware: the sample script will also unpack symlinks, and will unpack `../../../../etc/passwd` without complaining.  The rubyzip gem expects you to do your own pathname laundering.

Note that in rubyzip 1.1.4, `Zip::Zipfile` was renamed to `Zip::File`.